# Connection 1-form, symplectic potential?

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, connections, line-bundles

I recently encountered a formula that fell a little bit from the sky:

Given: A symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, a Hermitian line bundle $\pi:B\rightarrow M$, a connection $\nabla$ on $B$ and a symplectic potential $\theta$ (where $d\theta = \omega$), it holds that
\begin{equation} \nabla s_1 = -i\theta s_1, \end{equation}
where $s_1$ stands for the frame of $B$ (so that, for any section $s\in\Gamma(B)$ it is possible to express $s$ as $s= fs_1$, with $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a complex function.

How can one derive the above equation for the connection? What's the background?

Comment: Writing $-i\theta\otimes s_1$ would make more sense, I took a few seconds to parse this. The way the situation is phrased, I don't see why $\nabla$ and $\theta$ should be related at all. I can only see this as a definition (which works because $s_1$ is a global frame, but depends on the choice of $s_1$). The curvature $2$-form of $\nabla$ relative to $s_1$ equals $\omega$ up to a $\pm i$ factor, so $(B,\nabla)$ becomes a pre-quantized line bundle for $(M,g)$. This would sort of make sense since quantizations are not unique.

Comment: (oops: obviously meant $(M,\omega)$ above, too late to edit now)